# Combining multiple Http streams with RxJS Observables in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I tried to make the following stream work, with map and flatMap, however  it does what it should do, but the code is not optimal e.g the second time I am using flatMap, I never read it's response value, but I just don't know how to continue the flow without, and if I remove it I get an error

> Argument of type 'Observable' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type '(outerValue: any, innerValue: void, outerIndex: number,
>   innerIndex: number) => any'

So how can I make this better ?

```
  person;
  facility;
  apiUrl1: string = 'http://localhost:3000/person/?';
  apiUrl2: string = 'http://localhost:3000/facility/?';
  apiUrl3: string = 'http://localhost:3000/exposure/?';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData(arg): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl1 + arg.data)
      .map((response: any) =>
        this.person = response
      )
      .flatMap((response: any) => this.http.get(this.apiUrl2 + response.val1)
        .map((response: any) => {
          this.facility = response
        })
        .flatMap((response: any) => this.http.get(this.apiUrl3 + this.person.val2)
          .map((response: any) => response.val5 * this.facility.val3)))
  }
}
```

Comment: Where does the error happens?

Comment: If the problem is that in the last `flatMap` you never use the `response` argument, then you can use the following syntax `() => this.http.get(this.apiUrl3 + this.person.val2)`. You need to use `flatMap` since you are calling again `http.get` which returns an Observable

Comment: Also, your map() callbacks don't return anything, so response in the flatMap callbacks are undefined. Replace map() by do(). If you didn't use `any` everywhere, but instead used proper types, the compiler would catch those errors for you. any is evil. Don't use any.

Comment: yes it is.  you mean to use flatMap without the response argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention of having variables `this.person`, `this.facility` and `this.exposure` is to "retain" the values just so that you can re-use the results of your previous http call, then there is no need to do so. With the help of `.forkJoin` and [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), you can eliminate them.

Here is a much shorter, succinct and readable code:

```
getData(arg): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl1 + arg.data)
        .flatMap((person: any) => Observable.forkJoin([...this.http.get(this.apiUrl2 + person.val1), this.http.get(this.apiUrl3 + person.val2)]))
        .map(([facility, exposure]) => exposure.val5 * facility.val3)
}
```

*P/S: give proper names to your variables (as opposed to just naming them as `response`) helps a tonne*

Comment: doesn't this need to be inside  `getData(arg): Observable<any> {}` ?

Comment: @CodeWorm yes it does need to be. I am just writing out the most relevant part of the code. To prevent confusion I updated my answer.

Comment: I get following error: `Property 'forkJoin' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.`even if I import `import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';`

Comment: @CodeWorm which version of `rxjs` are you using? if you are using `rxjs6`, please read the migration guide - https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Comment: 5.5.7, this case should be `import 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';` still doesnt work

Comment: that is fixed but now I get: `Property 'val3' does not exist on type 'Object'.`